# Where are Enhancement prices for magic items?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, books

I'm a fairly new DM, and one of my players continually asks for page references for everything.

I have seen on the exchange plenty of questions regarding price adjustments when adding enhancement to magic items, but can you list the books & pages so I can shut him up? :)

Specifically where does it say that when you add an enhancement to an item (say a +1 sword), you must pay the total bonus price (say adding a +1) minus the current cost of the item?

And everything else related to buying and creating magic items, specifically price.

Comment: Have you considered lending the book to your player so he can check by himself? I mean, it's a collaborative effort, there's no reason to put all the work on the DM.

Comment: I have, but they say they haven't "found" anything?

Answer (score 8):

*Dungeon Master’s Guide* pg. 288 has this:

> #### Adding New Abilities
>
> A creator can add new magical abilities to a magic item with no restrictions. The cost to do this is the same as if the item was not magical. Thus, a *+1 longsword* can be made into a *+2 vorpal longsword*, **with the cost to create it being equal to that of a *+2 vorpal sword* minus the cost of a *+1 sword*.**

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

This rule also appears in the System Reference Document, e.g. [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#addingNewAbilities). The SRD is a collection of most of the core rules of the game, for easy reference. These materials have been released under the Open Game License, so there are numerous websites that host it (with a variety of value-added features like hyperlinking between sections and search functionality), but they are the official rules, just the same as in *Player’s Handbook*, *Dungeon Master’s Guide*, *Monster Manual*, *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, *Deities & Demigods*, and *Epic Level Handbook*. The d20SRD.org website I linked is my preference for the SRD (clean enough layout, doesn’t get muddled with homebrew as tends to happen on the wikis), and also includes open content from *Unearthed Arcana*.