# What's it cost to make a +2 greatsword into a +3 adamantine greatsword?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, special-materials

I want to to make my *+2 greatsword* into a *+3 adamantine greatsword*. Can I? How much does that cost?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I edited your question a bit. (Omitting capital letters and apostrophes tends to attract downvotes. Making the title a question gives folks an idea of what to expect.  Added some tags to make indexing the question easier.) Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are Enhancement prices for magic items?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79884/where-are-enhancement-prices-for-magic-items)

Comment: @Adeptus Adding a special material to a weapon after the fact, I think, makes this question unique.

Comment: The answers below do a really good job of answering the question you asked. But they may not answer the question you didn't ask..specifically if there's a cheaper way of doing what you need.  Can I ask Why you want a +3 adamantine weapon?..there may be cheaper alternatives to your end goal

Answer (score 9):

### Typically, a weapon can't be made from adamantine *after* the weapon's created…

When a weapon's created, it's made of a certain material (usually steel), and it can't, later, be made of a *different* material except through, for example, time travel.

#### …But the DM may allow doing so anyway

A *+2 greatsword* costs 8,350 gp. A *+3 adamantine greatsword* costs 21,050 gp. A really nice GM to whom you owe pizza has the PC pay the difference—12,700 gp—and end up with a *+3 adamantine greatsword*.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I actually figured out i could just improve my current gs , do you mind doing some math 1 more time?

Comment: Other than time travel, it would be much easier to just trade-in the +2 steel sword for a similar (+1?) adamantine sword (assuming there is one available in the shop) then pay the costs (including time) of boosting that sword to +3.

Comment: @LeHill One only needs time travel if one wants *the sword one already has* to become adamantine. Selling the old sword (for half price) and buying a new sword (for full price) doesn't change the *old* sword's special material! `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

A masterwork Adamantine Greatsword costs 3050gp, which is 50gp for a Greatsword plus 3000gp to make it from [Adamantine](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm#adamantine) (which is always Masterwork).

A +3 enchantment added to a weapon adds a cost of +18,000gp to the value of the end result.

So a +3 Adamantine Greatsword would be 21,050gp.. However.. IF you're looking for a way to turn your +2 Greatsword into a +3 Adamantine greatsword.. you'd have to sell the +2 Greatsword at a loss which would get you around 4,000gp-6,000gp depending on your diplomacy/bluff check to sell it.. And the money gained from that could be used to purchase your +3 Adamantine Greatsword. So after the sale of your sword you'd be looking at approximately 15,050gp-17,050gp.

Another way to do it is to cast Wish and use it to get it that way as well.. Though finding someone to cast wish could be a bit more difficult than finding the adamantine sword outright.

The main reason you'd normally be making an Adamantine anything as far as weapons are concerned is likely to bypass the hardness of weaker weapons, or objects for something like a Sunder Armor/weapon build most likely. Adamantine daggers are useful in this aspect as they shear through doors like a hot knife through butter.

Comment: That would be exactly what im going for, i already took improved sunder. Although with the way the thief in the party has been rolling the dagger might be a good idea too.

Comment: This seems like the better answer. It's a bit like asking "How can I turn my Mazda Miata into a BMW Roadster?" Well it's easy! Step 1 is you sell your Miata for standard used car prices.... (and if the player wants a good deal on this, it should be exactly like arguing with used car salesmen.... "No no this steel greatsword +2 is as good as new! Only took it with me to church! Not a speck of demon blood on this thing! Zombie brains? No, that's just a little flyspeck, rubs right off. You could resell this for full price easy!")

Comment: If your DM allows the *Artificer* class in your game (was introduced in the Ebberon campaign setting, if I recall correctly...) - you can also follow this "recipe": ingredients: (1) your magical +2 sword (2) an adamantine masterwork non-magical sword. process: (1) Have an artificer remove the magic from your +2 sword, and use it to enchant the adamantine sword. (2) follow normal process to turn +2 adamantine sword to +3 adamantine sword...